# Not allowed to load local resource [image upload]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, tmp

Here is my snippet that `ajax` a server-side script that uploads the file being submitted. It triggers on `change` of the `input[type=file]`.

```
    $('#magLogo').on('change', function(e) {
        var $input = $(this);
        var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('file', file);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          url: 'my/path/to/upload/script.php'
        })
          .done(function(fullPath) {
            $input
                .parents('#magLogoCont')
                .css('background-image', "url('"+fullPath+"')");
          });
    });
```

On the other side, the PHP script returns a JSON string that contains the temporary directory of the uploaded file (which looks like `file:///C:/wamp/tmp/filename.jpg` as I'm running on Windows).

The problem is when I want to put this image as the background of a div to show to the user that it has been uploaded, the error I get in the console says `Not allowed to load local resource`). I cannot upload it directly in the final directory as all information are not available by the time the user chooses its image to upload.

Is there a way of doing what I want to do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot integrate a file to the browser via such an "url"/path.

Move the Image to a folder under your httpfiles root of the web-page and direct to that path in a relative way.